# Possible to eliminate this base-class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, templates, subclass

Is there any way to eliminate the explicit constructor call in Foo and somehow have Bar::len assigned to the size of any of Bar's sub-classes?

```
class Bar
{
    size_t len_;

    Bar(size_t len) : len_(len) { }
};

class Foo : public Bar
{    
    Foo() : Bar(sizeof(Foo)) { }
};
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. Explicit constructor can a misleading term because of things like `explicit Bar(size_t len)`.

Comment: Not that I know of. The Bar subclass has no way of knowing of the size of its most derived type.

Comment: How about a virtual member `len()` that returns `sizeof(*this)`, overridden in every derived class?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Don't virtual functions not work in the constructor/destructor?

Comment: @MooingDuck: well, there'd be no reason to use the constructor at all in that version...

Comment: @KerrekSB: oh, I assumed you were going to initialize `len_` from `len()`.  Your way is good too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a "curiously recursive template" to inform the base class of the derived class's type:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Bar
{
    size_t len_;
protected:
    Bar() : len_(sizeof(Derived)) {}
};

class Foo : public Bar<Foo>
{
};
```

Comment: Thats kind of defeats the purpose of inheritance because you can't downcast without knowing the derived type.

Comment: +1 for CRTP. @Dani: The approach can perfectly be applied: `class base { int len; base(int l) : len(l) {} }; template <typename T> class base_t : base { base_t() : base( sizeof(T) ) {} };` and then derive all classes from the `base_t` template, rather than `base`. There is nothing that cannot be achieved by an extra level of indirection :)

Comment: @Dani: Can you elaborate? I don't really see what downcasting has to do with either my answer, or the "purpose of inheritance".

Comment: The question technically doesn't say "direct subclasses" so I don't think this would work for grandchildren. It works fine for a one-level inheritance though.

Comment: Actually @MikeSeymour's answer fits the bill perfectly - at least for my specific needs!

Comment: @MikeSeymour: this thing without David's workaround removes a huge feature of inheritance, and I thought it should be warned about.

Comment: @Dani: Oh I see, you meant there's no longer a common base class, so you can't write (non-template) code that can handle any subclass. That's true, and David's extra base class solves it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

virtual inheritance might do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar
{
    size_t len_;
public:
    Bar(size_t len) : len_(len) {std::cout << len << '\n';}
};

class Foo : virtual public Bar //virtual inheritance
{    
    size_t foo_bigger_than_bar;
public:
    Foo() : Bar(sizeof(Foo)) { } //Bar only called if Foo is most derived
};

class Derived2: public Foo
{    
    size_t derived2_bigger_than_foo;
public:
    Derived2() : Bar(sizeof(Derived2)), Foo() { }
    // since Foo virtually derives from Bar, we have (get) to 
    // initialize Bar ourselves.
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    std::cout << '\n';
    Derived2 d;
}
```

A virtual base class is only initialized by the most derived class.  Eg, when creating a `Derived2`, `Foo`'s constructor will *not* construct the Bar object, since `Derived2` already constructed it.  This is key for diamond inheritance, like `std::fstream`.
Demo here: http://codepad.org/HUlLB4Uq

Comment: Oh, I thought the concern was getting the size right, didn't realize it was eliminating the initializer altogeather.  Oops.